# Does Windows 8.1 Alert You if an update fails

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I know that when some things (errors, crashes, etc) happen in Windows, Windows does not alert you at directly.  With Windows updates, will you always get an alert or does Windows not tell you.  Here is something that I was reading that peaked my curiosity:
https://community.tenable.com/s/article/How-to-Get-a-List-of-All-of-the-Installed-Updates-on-Windows
"It is possible for an update to show as installed in the 'View Installed Updates' section and Not show up in the qfe list. That is usually an indication that the update did not install correctly or fully."

Comment: "Does Windows 8.1 Alert You if an update fails" Alert? Yes if it fails during the update process, No, not in the context of your question, updates that install incorrectly are not flagged as failures.

Comment: Since it doesn't alert you, how can I view a list of updates that installed incorrectly or didn't install at all?

Comment: It can install incorrectly but still show as installed in the list of installed updates. If it did not install at all then windows updates will offer it again. You cannot view a list, you have to manually compare the qfe output to the installed list of installed updates, this is a pain but is the only way to find the ones that installed incorrectly.